# Problem with registering Camel LogListener in version 3.x

Tags: apache-camel

I have been using camel LogListener to intercept all log messages from log EIP and massage those with some custom headers and exchange properties. All seemed to be working fine until we migrated from v2.23.x to v3.19.0. Ever since we upgraded, the LogListener has stopped working.

Before migration, we only did this:

```
            log.info("Registering log listener");
            getContext().addLogListener(new CustomLogListener());
```

And then our CustomLogListener looked like:

```
public class CustomLogListener implements LogListener {

    @Override
    public String onLog(final Exchange exchange, final CamelLogger camelLogger, final String message) {
        return String.format("traceId=%s TXN=%s TENANT=%s %s",exchange.getProperty(TOP_TRACEID, String.class),exchange.getProperty(TRANSACTION_ID, String.class), exchange.getProperty(TOPUP_ENV_HEADER, String.class), message);
    }
}
```

After migration, we no longer can do context.addLogListener(...)

We tried the following:

`TopLogListener logListener = new TopLogListener(); getContext().getRegistry().bind("logListener", logListener);`

but it didn't help. Any leads would be much appreciated.

P.S: Our application uses Jakarta JEE and is packaged as a war file and deployed in wildfly. It doesn't use spring boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Camel 3.19.x you can register the `LogListener` like:

```java
MyCustomLogListener logListener = new MyCustomLogListener();
getCamelContext().adapt(ExtendedCamelContext.class).addLogListener(logListener)
```

There's some more background info in the Camel 2.x - 3.x migration guide about APIs that got moved from `CamelContext` to `ExtendedCamelContext`:

https://camel.apache.org/manual/camel-3-migration-guide.html#_extended_camelcontext

Comment: Worked like a charm James. Thank you so much. I went through this guide multiple times while doing the actual migration from v2.23.x to v3.19.0 and yet ended up overlooking this section. Unbelievable :(